# php 5.3.2 - $_get $_post is not working

Tags: php, apache, post, get, localhost

I run an apache server on my localhost with php and mysql support. The only problem is, that `$_GET` and `$_POST` are not working at all.

This is my html file:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="message.php" method="GET">
Enter your message here: <input type="text" name="msg" size="30">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my message.php file:

```
<?php
$input = $_GET('msg');
echo "$input";
?>
```

If I type "blablabla" into the text input field in my html it redirects me to [localhost]/message.php?msg=blablabla which is good but the php gives me an empty page.
I checked out the source code of [localhost]/message.php?msg=blablabla but it only has an empty  part and an empty  part.

Did I make any mistake or is this a bug?

Comment: Always set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` helps solving problems.

Answer (score 5):

You're using `$_GET` in the wrong way. `$_GET` is an array. So you have to use it in this way:

```
$_GET['msg'];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$input = $_GET('msg');
```

↓

```
$input = $_GET['msg'];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to test results in array to use,

```
print_r($_POST); //method post
print_r($_GET); //method get
print_r($_SERVER); //all variable server
```

Method POST and GET not function, that variable array so you can not use () but $bla[].

```
echo $_GET['msg'];
```